# How do I select multiple columns across tables with Laravel query builder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a Laravel Eloquent query where I am trying to select multiple columns from a MySQL table.

```
    $query = DB::connection('global')
        ->select(
            'mytable.id',
            'mytable.column1',
            'mytable.another_column',
            'mytable.created_at',
            'myothertable.id
        )
        ->from('mytable')
        ->get();
```

It looks like the select() function takes three arguments: query, bindings and useReadPdo. The above query gives me an error:

```
{"error":true,"message":"Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Database\\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, string given" }
```

How do I write a select with Laravel query builder for the above columns?

I am structuring the query in this way, because I am looking to have a join across another table like so:

```
    $query = DB::connection('global')
        ->select(
            'mytable.id',
            'mytable.column1',
            'mytable.another_column',
            'mytable.created_at',
            'myothertable.id
        )
        ->from('mytable')
        ->leftJoin('myothertable', function($join){
           $join->on('mytable.id', '=', 'myothertable.id');
        })
        ->get();
```

How do I use the select function to grab multiple columns across tables with Eloquent query builder?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use Eloquent ORM?

Comment: This is a complex query across tables with joins so doesn't really lend itself to eloquent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do I write a select with Laravel query builder for the above columns?

You can do:

```
$data = DB::table('mytable')
        ->join('myothertable', 'mytable.id', '=', 'myothertable.mytable_id')
        ->select(
            'mytable.id',
            'mytable.column1',
            'mytable.another_column',
            'mytable.created_at',
            'myothertable.id'
        )
        ->get();
```

You can read the [documentations here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins)