# Is there a shorter way of selecting multiple columns from same table from a Laravel joined query?

Tags: laravel, select, laravel-query-builder

I am using Laravel 8 and PHP 7.3 and have this Laravel query:

```
$data = DB::table('mytable')
->join('myothertable', 'mytable.id', '=', 'myothertable.mytable_id')
->select(
    'mytable.id',
    'mytable.column1',
    'mytable.another_column',
    'mytable.created_at',
    'myothertable.id'
)
->get();
```

As you see inside select statement the table name ('mytable') where 4 of it's columns is selected is repeated, I was wondering if there be any shorter possible form like this one which I am looking for:

```
$data = DB::table('mytable')
->join('myothertable', 'mytable.id', '=', 'myothertable.mytable_id')
->select(
    'mytable{id,column1,another_column,created_at}',
    'myothertable.id'
)
->get();
```

Note :) I robbed the query from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48653190/7995302).

Comment: There does not appear to be any jQuery in this question

Comment: @CertainPerformance you mean I should tag it as eloquent?

Comment: If the column names from mytable does not exists in myothertable then you can simply write the column names but if the same column names exists in both tables then you will have to give the table name.

Comment: @NaserNikzad It should probably be tagged as `laravel-query-builder`. It is neither Eloquent nor jQuery.

Comment: Sorry guys, my bad, I thought I typed query NOT JQuery, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do Is make the query yourself rather than using the built-in functions. The query would look something like this:

```
DB::select('SELECT id, column1, another_column, created_at FROM TABLE1 
JOIN (SELECT id from myothertable) AS TABLE2 on mytable.id = TABLE2.id')
```

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it's an alternative way of joining the data =)